# Voice recognition, is there a way I can determine what the user says, possibly via regex?

Tags: java, android, regex, android-2.2-froyo, voice-recognition

I'm using the voice recognition feature in android, I can speak into my device and be presented with a list of possible words.

When I say "start" it gives me the following words it thought it heard :

1. stocks
2. stock
3. stop
4. start
5. stops
6. starks

That list will depend on user accents amongst various other factors. Is there an easy way I can check that list for a specific word?

If a user issues the command "start" or "stop" I need to be able to tell the difference between the two commands.

My initial thought was to use a regex to check for "sta" or "sto" in any of the responses, is there a more effective way?

Comment: I'd recommend tagging this differently, possibly Java/Regex.  I think you'll find more people experienced in those areas than via Android.  Plus your question really isn't about voice recognition.  It is about how to parse/search the string Voice-recognition provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, I'd suggest that you generate a [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) for every word you get back, score the entire list against the Soundexes of the words you're looking for as a fraction of characters matched and use those scores to decide which word is more likely to be a match.

For example, *start* encodes to `S363` and *stop* encodes to `S310`.  Scoring those against the words as a percentage of characters matched results in the following table:

```
Word    Soundex  S363   S310
----    -------  ----   ----
stocks  S320     0.50   0.75
stock   S320     0.50   0.75
stop    S310     0.50   1.00
start   S363     1.00   0.50
stops   S312     0.50   0.75
starks  S362     0.75   0.50
                 ----   ----
Average Score    0.63   0.71
```

Unfortunately, this comes up with the wrong answer (the probability that you said *stop* is higher even though you know you said *start*) because your two words have a lot in common.  When the recognizer matches one of your target words and confuses it with another in the same go-'round, you really have no way of knowing which one the speaker actually said.

You can work around this by selecting words that aren't so similar, like *go* and *stop* or *begin* and *end*.  Then you can ditch the Soundex entirely and just look for your target words in the returned list.  You'll have to watch for this in other localizations for your application, because other languages can have similar problems (e.g., French, which has *allez* and *arrêtez*).

HTH.